# Why does input-append class break the width of the input in fluid grids?

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Field 1</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Field 2</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" />
                    <span class="add-on">%</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

And the following style:

input {
    width: 100%;
}​

Field 1's input box works as expected. However, field 2 seems to get some fixed width. Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it? I would like the appended to input to be the same 100% width within the span to match the other text fields.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PilotBob/erT7d/

Comment: That would be bootstrap css.

Comment: That's because you have another container, which is smaller than you think. 100% refers to the nearest ancestor only.

Comment: 100% should refer to the nearest ancestor with a specific width right? Are you saying input-append has a width set on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because on the second input, you have **another container**, `.input-append`, which is smaller than you think.

Setting it to `width:100%;` as well, **[solved this problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/erT7d/3/)**

Comment: Ah thanks. Could have sworn I tried that. I bet I forgot the . in the style.

Comment: The bad thing, the appended <span> is outside of the span8 grid. Is there anyway to have it be in the grid?

Comment: That would be a wee more complicated, but it's possible. Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because bootstrap changes the default `display` value of the `div` which has the `class` `input-append` from `block` to `inline-block`.

You can set the `width:100%` to have the input the same width as normal but the `add-on` will overflow or set it to `width:95%` to be the same.

[First solution with width:100%](http://jsfiddle.net/erT7d/5/)

[Second solution with width:95%](http://jsfiddle.net/erT7d/6/)

Comment: thanks... the 95% doesn't really work, because when you size the container the width difference is constant.

Answer (score 0):

I have saved this file and run it. No issues found

```
<style>
input{width: 100%;}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Field 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Field 2</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" />
                <span class="add-on">%</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But on your mentioned url it is not working i don't know why?
If somewhere else it is creating problems there may be some reasons

1. insufficient container width, omit the parent or container width will solve the problem
2. you may have overwrite the width later in the css, use "input { width: 100% !importtant;}"